# Unable to init from given binary data

Tags: php, laravel-5, base64

I'm trying to save image encoded by base64 using Intervention Image, laravel-5 Exception told me that "Unable to init from given binary data". 
anyone can help?

```
$png_url = "user-".time().".png";
$path = "/public/".$png_url;
Image::make(base64_encode($request['image']))->save($path);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
$png_url = "user-".time().".png";
$path = "/public/".$png_url;
$base=base64_decode($request['image']);
Image::make($base)->save($path);
?>
```

Comment: Isn't this the same thing as listed in the original question?

Comment: No, the OP was using **base64_encode()**, the answer is **base64_decode()**

Answer (score 0):

if your code works well on your localhost and you upload to a live server and you experience such error its sometimes caused by the path issue on windows server and ubuntu/etc servers.

In my case i changed all the `\` in my path to  `/`

That is:

```
Image::make(base64_decode($request['profile_pic']))->save(public_path('cdn\profile_pictures\/'.$imageName))->destroy();
```

to

```
Image::make(base64_decode($request['profile_pic']))->save(public_path('cdn/profile_pictures//'.$imageName))->destroy();
```

Hope this helps someone...Happy coding...